# Spark 1.6 apply function to column with dot in name/ How to properly escape colName

Tags: scala, apache-spark

To apply a function to a column in Spark, the common way (only way?) seems to be

`df.withColumn(colName, myUdf(df.col(colName))`

fine, but I have columns with dots in the name, and to access thecolumn, I need to escape the name with backtick " ` "

Problem is: if I use that escaped name, the .withColumn function creates a new column with the escaped name

```
df.printSchema
root
 |-- raw.hourOfDay: long (nullable = false)
 |-- raw.minOfDay: long (nullable = false)
 |-- raw.dayOfWeek: long (nullable = false)
 |-- raw.sensor2: long (nullable = false)

df = df.withColumn("raw.hourOfDay", df.col("raw.hourOfDay"))
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "raw.hourOfDay" among (raw.hourOfDay, raw.minOfDay, raw.dayOfWeek, raw.sensor2);
```

this works:

```
df = df.withColumn("`raw.hourOfDay`", df.col("`raw.hourOfDay`"))
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [raw.hourOfDay: bigint, raw.minOfDay: bigint, raw.dayOfWeek: bigint, raw.sensor2: bigint, `raw.hourOfDay`: bigint]

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- raw.hourOfDay: long (nullable = false)
 |-- raw.minOfDay: long (nullable = false)
 |-- raw.dayOfWeek: long (nullable = false)
 |-- raw.sensor2: long (nullable = false)
 |-- `raw.hourOfDay`: long (nullable = false)
```

but as you see the schema has a new escaped column name.

If i do the above and attempt to drop the old column with the escaped name, it will drop the old column, but after that any attempt to access the new column results in something like:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "`raw.sensor2`" among (`raw.hourOfDay`, `raw.minOfDay`, `raw.dayOfWeek`, `raw.sensor2`);
```

as if it's now understanding the backtick as par of the name and not an escape character.

So how do I 'replace' my old column with `withColumn` without changing the name?

(PS: note that my column names are parametric, so I use a loop over the names. I used specific string names here for clarity: the escape sequence really look like "`"+colName+"`" )

**EDIT:**

right now the only trick I found was to do:

```
for (t <- df.columns) {
      if (t.contains(".")) {
        df = df.withColumn("`" + t + "`", myUdf(df.col("`" + t + "`")))
        df = df.drop(df.col("`" + t + "`"))
        df = df.withColumnRenamed("`" + t + "`", t)
      }
      else {
        df = df.withColumn(t, myUdf(df.col(t)))
      }
    }
```

Not really efficient i guess...

**EDIT**:

The documentation state:

```
def withColumn(colName: String, col: Column): DataFrame
Returns a new DataFrame by adding a column 
or replacing the existing column that has the same name.
```

So replacing a column should not be a problem.
However as pointed by @Glennie below, using a new name works fine, so this may be a bug in Spark 1.6

Comment: this bug seems to have been fixed now:
https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/13306

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the trick.

```
df = df.withColumn("`" + t + "`", myUdf(df.col("`" + t + "`")))
df = df.drop(df.col("`" + t + "`"))
df = df.withColumnRenamed("`" + t + "`", t)
```

It is working fine for me. Looking forward to see the better solution. Just to remind that we will be having similar issues with '#' character too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can add a column with the same name as an existing column (and why would you?).

```
df = df.withColumn("raw.hourOfDay", df.col("`raw.hourOfDay`"))
```

will fail as you point out, but not because the name isn't properly escaped, but because the name is identical to an existing column.

```
df = df.withColumn("raw.hourOfDay_2", df.col("`raw.hourOfDay`"))
```

on the other hand will evaluate just fine :)

Comment: Thanks @Gleenie, however this is not the case: names with dots are interpreted as nested columns, and need to be escaped if they mean to be a root column. I think the problem is more a bug in Spark where it interprets names differently in `withColumn` and `df.col`. 
The documentation explicitly says that `withColumn` will create a new column or replace the column if it exists. It works fine if I use a normal column name or if I substitute `.` with `#` for example.

Comment: note: I tried your code and it does work and create a column with the name `raw.hourOfDay_2`, which is interesting, but still doesn't when 'replacing' the column as the documentation says it should

Comment: PPS: You ask: why would you? Because as you see in my example I use this to do value mapping. Do you know another way to change data type for example?

Comment: I see. I didn't actually realise that you could replace the column like that :) In that case, you should report it as a bug.

Comment: do you know of any other way to do value mapping? or do you just create new columns when you do so?

Comment: I just create new columns and use `select` to filter away the columns I don't need. I'm pretty sure that the creation of the new column and the following `select` is processed in a single pass of the data, but I honestly haven't checked. I don't really use `withColumn` a lot... :-|